# Segmented controls in iWatch

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, user-experience, watchkit, ios8.3

I would like to create a control for `Apple Watch` (using `WatchKit`) that resembles the iPhone `UISegmentedControl`.

[image]

Has anyone managed to achieve this on `Apple Watch` already?

---

I followed the suggestion of a user and used buttons and custom background colours to achieve this. However the issue I got now is that they **do not align horizontally**. Any way to do so?

[image]

Comment: I have no ready solution, but this can be achieved with two buttons and custom background.

Comment: thanks Kelin, I added an edit

Comment: Oh you should use group with horizontal layout. You can read developer guide to be up on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your controls into `WKInterfaceGroup`,set its layout to Horizontal and tweak controls width in Interface Builder.Set spacing explicitly to 0 to override default value(2 pts).Here is the screenshot that illustrates the result.

[image]

Comment: Just drag WKInterfaceGroup into your WKInterfaceController from Object Library.Currently WKInterfaceGroup can't be added programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

Place your buttons in group with horizontal layout, make their widths relative to container with 0.5 value. Also you can set zero cornerRadius for buttons.

[image]

Comment: FYI: The cornerRadius has to be changed on the group

Answer (score 0):

You can group your buttons as Vladimir described if you really want to create a segmented control.  However, if you do, you should probably use a shorter label than "Standby" for the third option, so that your tap targets can all have a consistent size.

Also, you might consider reworking your UI in such a way that you can eliminate the third option, be more explicit about what you're controlling, and use built-in controls with larger targets.  For example, would something like this be possible?

[image: Reworked UI with standard controls]